# What SQL Database Permissions are required for SYSTEM_VERSIONING ON AND OFF

Tags: sql-server, temporal-tables

[The docs say that `SYSTEM_VERSIONING` requires the following permissions:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-table-security?view=sql-server-ver16#security-of-the-alter-temporal-table-set-system_versioning-onoff-statement)

> `CONTROL` permission on the original table which is altered
> `CONTROL` permission on the history table specified as part of the `ALTER TABLE` statement

I understand `CONTROL` is part of the db_owner permissions.
However this does not work, I created a local user, granted it db_owner role

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ASYSTEMVERSIONEDTABLE] SET (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = OFF)
GO
```

gives error:

> Cannot find the object "dbo.ASYSTEMVERSIONEDTABLE" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.

Question: Is there any database level permission that can be added to the user for this operation to work, or do I need to give it server permissions

Comment: There's not much more you can do aside from granting db_owner (which you said you did). Can you confirm that the account you provisioned is indeed a) db_owner and b) having the issue? I like to do `execute as user 'yourUser'; select * from sys.user_token; alter table... ; revert`. I also like looking at `sys.fn_my_permissions` while impersonating the user.

Comment: I can assign sysadmin server role and then it works, but it is not appropriate for an application to have server sysadmin permissions

Comment: As mentioned: what output do you get when running as that user and `select * from sys.fn_my_permissions('dbo.ASYSTEMVERSIONEDTABLE', 'OBJECT')`

Comment: You probably need ALTER on the schema and CONTROL on both the main table and the history table. It might just be best to create a SP, sign it with the correct permissions and give the user EXEC on the SP.

Comment: @Aardvark - While I agree in re: permissions required, the OP said that they granted db_owner which implies those permissions. The weird part for me is that that isn't sufficient.

Comment: But also! What need is there for a non-admin account to enable/disable system versioning? It's probably my insufficiently sophisticated imagination, but doing so seems like an extraordinary operation.

Comment: It definitely is an extra ordinary operation. In this case development team had changed their mind about a keyword and wanted to update the history table using a migration script in the pipeline

Comment: @BenThul Quite a standard case where a user is made a db_owner and is allowed to do anything they want with their own DB but not mess with the instance as a whole.

Comment: @Charlieface - "user is made a db_owner" = "user is an admin", imo.

Comment: @BenThul Only as far as that DB is concerned. You don't want to make this user `superadmin`

Comment: There is no superadmin role, there are db roles and server roles. application should be limited to the database and should not need server roles. This particular operation, SYSTM_VERSIONING on and off needs server permissions.

Comment: I must say, I cannot repro this issue with an SQL fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1e5e1c45e4ab8e1764e91495a840019e. Perhaps the user ha a `DENY` on something. What are the results of `sys.fn_my_permissions` for the server, database and the actual table?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this with:

```
GRANT ALTER ON SCHEMA :: [dbo] TO user;
```

This statement grants the user the ability to alter any objects within the `[dbo]` schema, not only tables but also views, procedures, etc. It's a more targeted permission than granting CONTROL on individual tables, as it focuses on the schema level.